# Prevent MySQL query from timing out in Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Our client's online shop uses Opencart, for marketing purposes they wanted to sync Opencart orders automatically with Google Sheets. I modified a script in google sheets to extract customer orders from the past year (based on https://www.transpacific-software.com/blog/opencart-to-google-docs-pull-and-sync-data-auto-through-scripting and https://gist.github.com/pradeepbheron/e6129c9fd9bc74e814d0)

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT order_id, firstname AS first_name, lastname AS last_name, 
email, date_added AS order_date, CONCAT("£", FORMAT(total,2)) 
order_value, payment_address_1 AS billing_address_1, 
payment_address_2 AS billing_address_2, payment_city AS 
billing_city, payment_postcode AS billing_postcode, 
payment_country AS billing_country, items_purchased FROM 
(
    SELECT order_id, firstname, lastname, email, date_added, 
    total, payment_address_1, payment_address_2, payment_city, 
    payment_postcode, payment_country 
    FROM ocbw_order 
    GROUP BY order_id
) AS A 
JOIN (
     SELECT order_id AS product_order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name 
     SEPARATOR ", ") AS items_purchased 
     FROM ocbw_order_product 
     GROUP BY product_order_id
) AS B 
     ON A.order_id=B.product_order_id 
     WHERE date_added >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
     AND firstname != ''
```

It runs fine in phpMyAdmin but Google Script Editor generates an "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.

It looks like there are 7357 rows (exported from myPhpAdmin). Is there a better way to write the query? Also I am trying to rename the column headers but can only two works, i.e:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ", ") AS items_purchased
```

and

```
CONCAT("£", FORMAT(total,2)) order_value
```

Any thoughts

**QUICK UPDATE: Fri Nov  9 11:54:03 2018**

1) As request by @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, here is a screenshot of the explain table result

[image]

2) I looked into the Best Practices doc mentioned by @bcperth. I tried to rewrite the google sheets script but ran into issues.

Here is the amended script.

```
function p1MySQLFetchData() { 

    // Change it as per your database credentials
    var conn = 
    Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://[dbHostIp]:3306/[dbName]', 
    '[dbUsername]', '[dbPassword]'); 

    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    var start = new Date(); // Get script starting time

    //change table name as per your database structure
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery('[sqlQuery]'); 
    // It sets the limit of the 
    // maximum nuber of rows in a ResultSet object

    // Returns the currently active spreadsheet
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
    var row = 0;

    // Mysql table column name count.
    var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 

    // Create array to hold mysql data
    var tempArray = []; 

    // get row and column count for later
    var colCount = getCount;

    // ATTEMPT TO GET ROW COUNT 1 
    //rs.last();
    //var rowCount = rs.getRow();
    //rs.beforeFirst(); // resets rs cursor
    //Logger.log(RowCount); 
    // DOESN'T WORK! result => ReferenceError: "RowCount" is not 
    // defined. (line 28, file "Code")

    // ATTEMPT TO GET ROW COUNT 2
    //var rsCount = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM 
    //[sqlQuery]); 
    // It sets the limit of the maximum number of rows in a ResultSet 
    // object
    //rsCount.next();
    //var rowCount = rsCount.getString("rowcount");
    //Logger.log(rowCount); 
    // DOESN'T WORK!  result => 0


    // Build TempArray using MySQL data
    for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++){ 
        tempArray[0][i] = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1); 
        // DOESNT WORK => ERROR 
        // TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "order_id". 
        // (line 39, file "Code")
        //Logger.log(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
    }  

    var row = 1; 
        while (rs.next()) {
           for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 
           col++) { 
                tempArray[row][col] = rs.getString(col + 1);
                //Logger.log(rs.getString(col + 1));
            }
        row++;
    }

    // BELOW DOESNT AS I CANT GET A ROW COUNT (SEE ABOVE)
    // Fill Spreadsheet from tempArray 
    //for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        //for (var col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
            //cell.offset(row, col).setValue(tempArray[row][col + 1]);
        //}
    // }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    var end = new Date(); // Get script ending time
    Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())); 
    // To generate script log. To view log click on View -> Logs.
}
```

But as you can see from the comments, I get loads of errors. Am not sure what to do next.

**UPDATE Fri Nov 30 15:26:14 2018**

In answer to @Tedinoz comment below.

PhpMyAdmin generates 6862 results and the query took 13.3074 seconds.

When I ran the script in Googles Script Editor, it took around 2 minutes 30 to complete and only pulls 6348 records (92.5%). The records stop after 3rd October 2018.

Regarding your suggestions:

1) I tried running a modified script, setting the INTERVAL to:

- 1 MONTH => I get no results in Google (it should be 529)
- 2 MONTH => I get 14 results (should be 1029)
- 3 MONTH => I get 299 results (should be 1669).

They all took about 4-7 second in myPhpAdmin vs 5 - 20 seconds for Google Script Editor

2) Do you mean exporting a csv from phpMyAdmin and importing to Google Sheets? Well I did that and it works fine.

Another thing I have noticed is that the order_id's in Google Sheets don't match that from phpMyAdmin. Weird.

Comment: prefix your query with `explain` and paste output

Comment: The first link is dead, so we cannot see the script. The second link has code that may be inefficient, in that the code is updating the sheet on a per col, per row basis. This is very bad,. Look here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices under the heading "Use batch operations". I'm guessing the SQL is not your problem, but how you update the sheet.

Comment: One simple optimalization is to put that WHERE clause inside subquery A. But that won't have effect on sub-query B.

Comment: Thanks for the tips so far (@ ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, @ bcperth and @ LukStorms). I am stuck right now so any additional feedback would be welcome.

Comment: @neaham How are you going with your OpenCart/Mysql/Google scripts problem? Worked it out, or still needing help?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz. No I got nowhere with this. So I left it. If you have any suggestions  it would be welcome.

Comment: @neahan How long does phpmyadmin take to run the sql? How complex is your spreadsheet, how long does it take to recalculate? From the point of view of testing, have you tried i) limiting the number of records for the db=> Google link, or 2) exporting a csv file, and then importing into a Google sheet just confirm that "all is well" (so to speak)?

Comment: @Tedinoz Please see my update above. Thanks.

Comment: @neahan Thanks for the new info. Yes, I did beat export csv and import manually. There is a serious problem if the order_id is not lining up; at face value the data imported in Google sheets is not safe or reliable..

Comment: @neahan The Column headers seem fine. Order value is missing "AS". It should be `CONCAT("£", FORMAT(total,2)) AS order_value`

Comment: @neahan Try `SELECT A.order_id, firstname AS first_name, lastname AS last_name, email, date_added ,CONCAT("£", FORMAT(A.total,2)) AS order_value, payment_address_1, payment_address_2, payment_city, payment_postcode, payment_country, GROUP_CONCAT(B.name) AS items_purchased
FROM oc_order AS A
LEFT JOIN oc_order_product AS B
ON A.order_id = B.order_id
WHERE A.date_added >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND A.firstname != ''
GROUP BY A.order_id` I got a 7% improvement on small OpenCart volumes. it 'might' improve on higher volumes.

Comment: @neahan FWIW, there was a question recently on a similar topic. Fast export from the DB but timing out via Google script. It turned out that the spreadsheet was enormous and was taking over a minute to recalculate - no wonder the import was timing out. When imported into a blank spreadsheet, the execution time was a matter of seconds. Could this be a factor in your case? Have you tried importing into a blank/clean spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tedinoz. Thanks for the tips. I will give them a try